# discord.py Use buttons for pages

Tags: python, discord.py

I am not too new to python but not very experienced in it and I am not sure how exactly to use discord buttons and classes to do this. I already know how to use reactions but I think buttons are better.

I have tried many methods of how you could add buttons and the buttons do get added however clicking them doesnt give the response I want.

My Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
  pages=["page1","page2","page3","page4"]
  button1=Button(label="<",style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
  button2=Button(label=">",style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
  page=0
  async def button1_callback(interaction):
    if page>0:
      return await interaction.response.edit_message(content=pages[page-1])
      page-=1
    else:
      return
  async def button2_callback(interaction):
    if page<len(pages)-1:
      return await interaction.response.edit_message(content=pages[page+1])
      page+=1
    else:
      return
  button1.callback= button1_callback
  button2.callback= button2_callback
  view=View()
  view.add_item(button1)
  view.add_item(button2)
  await ctx.send(pages[page],view=view)
```

I want it so that clicking the forward arrow add 1 and send page2,3 etc and the backward arrow the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `page` variable inside your callback functions does not refer to the `p`age variable you defined in your `button` function. Lets try to use `nonlocal` to make sure the callback functions refer to the correct `page` variable.

edit: modified my code on commentaries of Łukasz Kwieciński, the code will be defined outside the function and we pass pages as a parameter to the constructor of the class and making the page variable an instance variable

```
from discord.ui import Button, View
from discord import ButtonStyle

class PaginationView(View):
    def __init__(self, pages):
        super().__init__()
        self.page = 0
        self.pages = pages

        self.add_item(Button(label="<", style=ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="prev"))
        self.add_item(Button(label=">", style=ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="next"))

    @discord.ui.button(custom_id="prev")
    async def prev_button(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        if self.page > 0:
            self.page -= 1
            await interaction.response.edit_message(content=self.pages[self.page])

    @discord.ui.button(custom_id="next")
    async def next_button(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        if self.page < len(self.pages) - 1:
            self.page += 1
            await interaction.response.edit_message(content=self.pages[self.page])

@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    pages = ["page1","page2","page3","page4"]
    await ctx.send(pages[0], view=PaginationView(pages))
```

Comment: Why are you creating a class inside of a function? It's stupid, useless and a waste of resources. It gets redefined every time you run the command. Put it outside the command and make the `page` variable an instance variable, also pass the `pages` as an argument to the constructor of the class.

Comment: you right, I modified my answer

Comment: Thanks for this however I think the self.add_item isn't needed as it causes me an error and instead add the label and button style in the @discord.ui.button, other than that it works!

Answer (score 2):

So, it did not work for me and I did my research on the discord api reference site, came up with this code, which is 100% **WORKING** :

```
class PaginationView(View):
def __init__(self, pages):
    super().__init__()
    self.page = 0
    self.pages = pages

@discord.ui.button(label="<", style=ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="prev") #, emoji="" if wanted
async def prev_button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
    if self.page > 0:
        self.page -= 1
    else:
        self.page = len(self.pages) - 1
    await interaction.response.edit_message(content=self.pages[self.page])

@discord.ui.button(label=">", style=ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="next") #, emoji="" if wanted
async def next_button(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
    if self.page < len(self.pages) - 1:
        self.page += 1
    else:
        self.page = 0
    await interaction.response.edit_message(content=self.pages[self.page])
@bot.tree.command()
async def button(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    pages = ["page1", "page2", "page3", "page4"]
    await interaction.response.send_message(pages[0], view=PaginationView(pages))
```

It is safer to create the command `button`, as being an app commands / slash command, because if you work with interactions for it is tricky to use context variables for the actual command, I suggest you to use tree commands / slash commands for this type of things.

I also implemented the state where you are for example on page 1 and you click previous page, the above code will lead the bot to take you to the last page, other then just failing the interaction, same for the 4th page or the final page when you want to go to the next page the next page will be the 1st.
I did this just because, better you handle problems than ignoring them.

Also in the `super().__init__()` line if you add `timeout=None` as a param of `__init__()` ->> `super().__init__(timeout=None)` your buttons won't stop working anymore, even when restarting the bot.

**WHEN DOING THIS IN A COG**
You must change the
`@bot.tree.command() async def button(interaction:discord.Interaction)` in `@app_commands.command() async def button(self, interaction:discord.Interaction)`